# How can I improve the performance of a three.js script?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, three.js

I have a really nice js animation that i would like to use as a website background. Unfortunately it seems to be very intensive in CPU/GPU usage. The animation itself runs quite smooth, but my GPU is at 100%. other animations on the website don't run smooth at all and seem to lag.

I already looked at other Stackoverflow posts concerning boosting the performance of three.js scripts, but the ideas didn't work for me yet. For example I reduced the calls from 600 down to 200 by reducing the "city" objects in order to improve performance, but GPU is still at 100%.

I updated three.js to the latest version and so on. Nothing worked so far. I am quite new to three.js and JS so please don't be too harsh with me. Also I didn't really know which parts of the code will really boost performance, so I included the whole thing - even though it is very long. I hope the comments help to skip to the right parts.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    // Three JS Template
//----------------------------------------------------------------- BASIC parameters
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
  renderer.shadowMap.needsUpdate = true;

};
document.getElementById('animated-bg').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
};

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );

camera.position.set(0, 2, 14);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var city = new THREE.Object3D();
var smoke = new THREE.Object3D();
var town = new THREE.Object3D();

var createCarPos = true;
var uSpeed = 0.001;

//----------------------------------------------------------------- FOG background

var setcolor = 0x862834;

scene.background = new THREE.Color(setcolor);
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(setcolor, 10, 16);

//----------------------------------------------------------------- RANDOM Function
function mathRandom(num = 8) {
  var numValue = - Math.random() * num + Math.random() * num;
  return numValue;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------- CHANGE bluilding colors
var setTintNum = true;
function setTintColor() {
  if (setTintNum) {
    setTintNum = false;
    var setColor = 0x000000;
  } else {
    setTintNum = true;
    var setColor = 0x000000;
  };
  //setColor = 0x222222;
  return setColor;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------- CREATE City

function init() {
  var segments = 2;
  for (var i = 1; i<50; i++) {
    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,0,0,segments,segments,segments);
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color:setTintColor(),
      wireframe:false,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
      side:THREE.DoubleSide});
    var wmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color:0xFFFFFF,
      wireframe:true,
      transparent:true,
      opacity: 0.03,
      side:THREE.DoubleSide});

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    var wire = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, wmaterial);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    var wfloor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, wmaterial);
    
    cube.add(wfloor);
    cube.castShadow = true;
    cube.receiveShadow = true;
    cube.rotationValue = 0.1+Math.abs(mathRandom(8));
    
    floor.scale.y = 0.05;//+mathRandom(0.5);
    cube.scale.y = 0.1+Math.abs(mathRandom(8));

    var cubeWidth = 0.9;
    cube.scale.x = cube.scale.z = cubeWidth+mathRandom(1-cubeWidth);
    cube.position.x = Math.round(mathRandom());
    cube.position.z = Math.round(mathRandom());
    
    floor.position.set(cube.position.x, 0/*floor.scale.y / 2*/, cube.position.z)
    
    town.add(floor);
    town.add(cube);
  };
  //----------------------------------------------------------------- Particular
  
  var gmaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({color:0xFFFF00, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
  var gparticular = new THREE.CircleGeometry(0.01, 3);
  var aparticular = 5;
  
  for (var h = 1; h<300; h++) {
    var particular = new THREE.Mesh(gparticular, gmaterial);
    particular.position.set(mathRandom(aparticular), mathRandom(aparticular),mathRandom(aparticular));
    particular.rotation.set(mathRandom(),mathRandom(),mathRandom());
    smoke.add(particular);
  };
  
  var pmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color:0x000000,
    side:THREE.DoubleSide,
    roughness: 10,
    metalness: 0.6,
    opacity:0.9,
    transparent:true});
  var pgeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60,60);
  var pelement = new THREE.Mesh(pgeometry, pmaterial);
  pelement.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI / 180;
  pelement.position.y = -0.001;
  pelement.receiveShadow = true;

  city.add(pelement);
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------- MOUSE function
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
var intersected;

function onMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
};
function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
  if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX -  window.innerWidth / 2;
    mouse.y = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - window.innerHeight / 2;
  };
};
function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
  if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX -  window.innerWidth / 2;
    mouse.y = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - window.innerHeight / 2;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
window.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

//----------------------------------------------------------------- Lights
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 4);
var lightFront = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 20, 10);
var lightBack = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);

var spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( lightFront );

lightFront.rotation.x = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
lightFront.rotation.z = -45 * Math.PI / 180;
lightFront.position.set(5, 5, 5);
lightFront.castShadow = true;
lightFront.shadow.mapSize.width = 6000;
lightFront.shadow.mapSize.height = lightFront.shadow.mapSize.width;
lightFront.penumbra = 0.1;
lightBack.position.set(0,6,0);

smoke.position.y = 2;

scene.add(ambientLight);
city.add(lightFront);
scene.add(lightBack);
scene.add(city);
city.add(smoke);
city.add(town);

//----------------------------------------------------------------- GRID Helper
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 60, 120, 0xFF0000, 0x000000);
city.add( gridHelper );

//----------------------------------------------------------------- CAR world
var generateCar = function() {
  
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------- LINES world

var createCars = function(cScale = 2, cPos = 20, cColor = 0xFFFF00) {
  var cMat = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({color:cColor, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
  var cGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, cScale/40, cScale/40);
  var cElem = new THREE.Mesh(cGeo, cMat);
  var cAmp = 3;
  
  if (createCarPos) {
    createCarPos = false;
    cElem.position.x = -cPos;
    cElem.position.z = (mathRandom(cAmp));

    TweenMax.to(cElem.position, 3, {x:cPos, repeat:-1, yoyo:true, delay:mathRandom(3)});
  } else {
    createCarPos = true;
    cElem.position.x = (mathRandom(cAmp));
    cElem.position.z = -cPos;
    cElem.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  
    TweenMax.to(cElem.position, 5, {z:cPos, repeat:-1, yoyo:true, delay:mathRandom(3), ease:Power1.easeInOut});
  };
  cElem.receiveShadow = true;
  cElem.castShadow = true;
  cElem.position.y = Math.abs(mathRandom(5));
  city.add(cElem);
};

var generateLines = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i<60; i++) {
    createCars(0.1, 20);
  };
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------- CAMERA position

var cameraSet = function() {
  createCars(0.1, 20, 0xFFFFFF);
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------- ANIMATE

var animate = function() {
  var time = Date.now() * 0.00005;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  city.rotation.y -= ((mouse.x * 8) - camera.rotation.y) * uSpeed;
  city.rotation.x -= (-(mouse.y * 2) - camera.rotation.x) * uSpeed;
  if (city.rotation.x < -0.05) city.rotation.x = -0.05;
  else if (city.rotation.x>1) city.rotation.x = 1;
  var cityRotation = Math.sin(Date.now() / 5000) * 13;
  for ( let i = 0, l = town.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
    var object = town.children[ i ];
  }
  
  smoke.rotation.y += 0.01;
  smoke.rotation.x += 0.01;
  
  camera.lookAt(city.position);
  renderer.render( scene, camera );  
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------- START functions
generateLines();
init();
animate();
```

Comment: I suggest you look at how you can redesign this to use fewer meshes

InstancedMesh for dynamic objects wherever you re-use a mesh & materials.
MergeBufferGeometries for everything static.

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=instancedmesh#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries

Answer (score 3):

There are many things you could do.

- For starters, you want to keep your `Mesh` number low to reduce drawcalls. This means that you shouldn't create one mesh for `cube` and one for `floor`. If they share the same material, just create 2 separate geometries, then merge them with [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=utils#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries).
- If you have 50 buildings with the same material, you should also merge them so they all draw at once.
- `MeshStandardMaterial` is pretty expensive to render, so since you're not using environment reflections, you should consider Phong or Lambert materials instead, which are much less resource-intensive.
- Shadows basically **double** your drawcalls per frame because it has to first calculate all shadow-casting geometries. If your buildings aren't going to move, set [`lightFront.shadow.autoUpdate = false`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shadow#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow.autoUpdate) after the first frame.
- Don't create a new circular Mesh for each particle. That's 300 meshes! Instead, use [THREE.Points](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=points#api/en/objects/Points), which has the capacity of drawing thousands of particles on a single drawcall, saving you tons of render time, as [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=point#webgl_buffergeometry_points).
- Don't set your renderer's [pixelRatio](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=renderer#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setPixelRatio) to anything above 1, if you do. That'd just kill your performance.

I don't have time to get into the car creation, but the same principle applies: try to reduce your drawcalls!